# Integrating ad in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, admob

I want to integrate ad to my app, but the problem is that the app crashes, **when I add ads to a fragment** instead of an activity.

Can anyone tell me the working code for it?

I had tried some methods, but they didn't work. If the code is placed in an activity it works correctly

Here is the code I tried for Fragment:

```
//it shows error in get application content and find view by id
// so I added get activity() and get view() to it

MobileAds.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx~33xxxxxxx");
AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: post the logcat

Comment: @UmarAta I bet on NPE ... because getView() is called from wrong time... Obviously OP doesn't know Fragment's basics like lifecycle

Comment: well i am not running on a emulator,but the app runs when i am trying to run the ad on activity instead of fragment

Comment: can you post the full method where the code in your  question present

Comment: @UmarAta the app runs perfectly when the ad is placed in activity,what is the error with it.?
just removing the getActivity() and getview() from the code,it runs perfectly in any other activity .

Comment: instead of getview you should inflate the layout of fragment then hold it in View v , then use v.findViewById(R.id.adView); , then it will work

Comment: can you please describe it in code ,

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this , I am supposed you placed your adView inside the xml(layout) of your fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);

 MobileAds.initialize(getActivity(), "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx~33xxxxxxx");
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        return v;
    }
```

Comment: i had done the same thing.still it does not work,but thanks for reply.

Comment: remove getapplicationcontext, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Get the inflated `view` and use that as a reference to find and bind your `adView`

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();
    if (view != null){
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```